# Which is the best iCloud approach for my iOS notes app with text, photo, audio & drawing notes. Should I choose document storage or CloudKit?

Tags: ios, iphone, icloud, cloudkit, icloud-documents

I am developing an iOS notes app where a user can add image, text, audio and drawing notes. I want to implement iCloud synchronization between multiple devices. Out of the 3 options (key value, document storage, CloudKit) which one should I choose? I would like to implement the sharing of notes (collaboration) among users as well. I am using core data as my DB currently.

Comment: What do you mean by document storage? Storing in iCloud Drive?

Comment: Apple provides the following iCloud storage APIs - 1) Key value Storage 2) iCloud document storage (mostly for document based apps) 3) CloudKit Storage. See link https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html . The link specifies the difference the three options.

Comment: I tried out iCloud's key-value storage option. It doesn't suit apps that are looking for instant sync between devices as we cannot manually fetch the data, so I'd not recommend that option. iCloud Drive (document storage visible to the user) might be suitable, if you don't mind that the user has direct access to the files. That can get quite messy, though, with many files. From a UX perspective, I'd not recommend that either. Idk about CloudKit, but it's the only option left. Or: use your own server and database. That's the most flexible option you have, but requires the most effort.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! If I use iCloud Drive (document storage with iCloud), how will things work if the user is offline or logged out of iCloud account?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure about that. You'll have to try it yourself or do more research. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Key-value storage is out of question due do being too limited for your goal, document storage is only recommended when you need to handle and store the document as a whole. Since you are already using `CoreData` for local storage, it only makes sense to use regular `CloudKit` with it for cloud storage and sharing.

Synchronisation of `CoreData` and `CloudKit` can be tough. I am personally using a combo of `RxCoreData` and `RxCloudKit` libraries which provide some relief in synchronisation and some syntax sugar too.

A word in advance about uniqueness constraints: for `CoreData`, you define them based on key(s) or hash of all values, for `CloudKit` it is only possible (and also required) for the `CKRecord` key, to the best of my knowledge. So it is best to take care of it from the very start.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It was helpful. Could you please also throw light on iCloud Document storage approach using File coordination (NSFileCoordinator)? With File coordination, conflicts can be handled automatically to a huge extent, whereas in CloudKit all conflicts need to be handled manually.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, CloudKit is the only opinion :)

I have a note app named `marknote`. And at the beginning I used iCloud document storage. It worked sometime, but not stable. The worst thing is, when and whether your documents can be synced is out of your control, instead it relies on Apple's daemon service. It becomes even worse when your documents are a little big, for instance several mega bytes.
So after fighting for some time, I changed to CloudKit. As @maxim-volgin has already pointed out, the implementation of CloudKit sync is tough, but it is reliable. And all headache just gone after switching to CloudKit.

Comment: Is the sync issue sorted and do the documents sync perfectly?